# Clarification on Tensorflow tensor shapes and matmul

Tags: tensorflow

I need some clarification on how Tensorflow treats the shape of its tensors. This is taken from the [MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros):

I define a placeholder that will at some later point be fed with some of my training data:

`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])`

During runtime I feed it in batches of 100, so its shape during runtime is `(100, 784)`. I also define weights and biases:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

`W`is of shape `(784, 10)` and `b`is of shape `(10)`. Now I compute

```
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
```

And this is where I am stuck. The matrix product of `x` and `W` is of shape `(None, 10)` or `(100, 10)` during runtime. However I can without error add vector `b` to it. This confuses me. How can this work? And is there some better documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator in `tf.matmul(x, W) + b` is actually shorthand for `tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)` (operator overloading).

The [documentation for `tf.add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) mentions that it supports [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which means that when you add a tensor with shape `(10)` to a tensor with shape `(100, 10)`, it's the equivalent of adding the `(10)` tensor to *each row* of the `(100, 10)` tensor.

Hope that helps